# Replacing tabs with commas in OSX bash shell script, keep getting No such file error

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm trying to create a script in OSX 10.12 to replace tabs with commas in a UTF-16 file containing Asian characters, "testdata.txt".

I have tried several variations of scripts, including:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '' -e's/ /,/g' testdata.txt

#!/bin/bash
sed 's/ /,/g' testdata.txt > newdata.txt

#!/bin/bash
find . -name 'testdata.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/a/g"
```

However, on running the scripts via double click, I keep getting the following error: `sed: testdata.txt: No such file or directory`

I wrote everything in plain text in TextEdit, changed the file extension to `.command`, and enabled them in Terminal with `chmod +x`. testdata.txt is in the same folder as the scripts.

Based on what I've seen I should be able to do this with one line of code, but no matter what I do I keep getting this error. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

Comment: `'testdata.txt"` Two different quote marks for this, also the sed command is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

You said you wanted to replace tabs (`\t`). However, `sed` does not understand `\t`, so you should do it like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed $'s/\t/,/g' testdata.txt > newdata.txt
```

The dollar sign before single quotes strings expands `\t`, `\n`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made a folder on the desktop with just "testdata.txt" the Shell script exactly as you've typed it, but I still keep getting "No such file or directory found".

Answer (score 0):

I find `tr` much simpler for transliterating single characters:

```
tr '\t' ',' < yourFile
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run the script as you've written, I don't get an error, but the contents of "testdata.txt" aren't altered at all.

Comment: Just to make sure the tab character isn't causing the issue, I tried the following:

Comment: `tr 'a' 'b' < testdata.txt` to see if I could change all instances of a to b, but even though it doesn't throw up an error there's no change to testdata.txt (Sorry I keep making new comments, apparently you can't line break on mobile)

Comment: `tr` is a filter, so it reads `stdin` and writes `stdout`. If you want it to write to a new file, you need to do `tr 'a' 'b' < inputFile > outputFile`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It looks like there were two issues:

1. The script wasn't executing in the folder it was located, hence the "No such file" error.
2. `sed` apparently doesn't play nice with UTF-16 encoding.

The code that eventually worked is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "`dirname "$0"`"         #points script to current folder
export LC_CTYPE=C           #makes UTF-16 work somehow
sed $'s/\t/,/g' testdata.txt > properlyformatted.csv
```